# Django - gettext problems with Umlauts

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I've got several longer translations in my django app. In the django doc they say:

> Long messages are a special case. There, the first string directly
>   after the msgstr (or msgid) is an empty string. Then the content
>   itself will be written over the next few lines as one string per line.
>   Those strings are directly concatenated. Don’t forget trailing spaces
>   within the strings; otherwise, they’ll be tacked together without
>   whitespace!

So in my app, it looks like this:

```
msgid ""
"Bitte validieren Sie vor dem ersten Login ihre E-Mail-Adresse mittels dem "
"angehängten Link in der E-Mail."
msgstr ""
"Please validate your e-mail before your first login."
```

But all these longer translations do not work! Anything else is translated. Any ideas?

EDIT:

This translation is used like that:

```
{% trans "Bitte validieren Sie vor dem ersten Login ihre E-Mail-Adresse mittels dem angehängten Link in der E-Mail." %}
```

But it also happens in the views, there I use ugettext_lazy.

It works everywhere else!

Comment: can you show how this msg is used as id? and how you are using gettext?

Comment: I edited the post, it's used with trans '', but it also happens in the views when I use ugettext_lazy

Comment: Is this entry marked as `fuzzy` in the `.po` file?

Comment: what if you deleted them from .po and run compilemessages again, what is the output will be in .po? is there duplicate in this msgid?

Comment: @Leistungsabfall No it's not

Comment: @AhmedHosny Well if I run compilemessages, it's obviously not doing anything. When I run makemessages again, the key gets generated and when I compile it, it's still not getting translated. It's not a duplicate btw

Comment: and after makemessages it appears in multiple lines ? Did you check is it will work if it is in a single line. sometimes if you used ugettext_lazy() with multiple lines, you will need to add `\n` to the msgid

Comment: @AhmedHosny Yes, that's the original state. It also doesn't work if the msgid is a single line

Comment: What if you wrote any other msgid in the same `{% trans %}`, is it get translated?

Comment: @AhmedHosny I checked this one, and yes - they do get translated

Comment: I checked the .po-File... it all seems to be ok

Comment: It seems that there is a problem with Umlauts

Comment: I think that you should add `u` before the string to handle the unicode characters like `ä`. So it should be like:

`{% trans u"Bitte validieren Sie vor dem ersten Login ihre E-Mail-Adresse mittels dem angehängten Link in der E-Mail." %}`

Comment: @AhmedHosny That's it! Thank you very much

Comment: @Dominic I've posted it as answer. Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should add u before the string to handle the unicode characters like `ä`. So it should be like: `{% trans u"Bitte validieren Sie vor dem ersten Login ihre E-Mail-Adresse mittels dem angehängten Link in der E-Mail." %}`